# Retrieve url from Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this following scenario

Open file from email attachment (gmail) -> View and save it to my app.

For this to handle i have added this in manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
                </category>

                <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="*/*"/>  
                <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="*/*"/>  


            </intent-filter>
```

When i fetch this data back i don't get the url back with intent.getData() or through extras.
I might be missing something very simple.

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

please do it in this way

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data
    android:mimeType="application/mytype"
    android:host="*" 
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.mytpe"
  />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It did not help. Does Android view intent sends URI ?